# C# UWP Live Charts Create CartesianChart dynamically in a Windows Runtime Application

Tags: c#, uwp, livecharts

I am trying to create a CartesianChart dynamically in a Windows Runtime Application.

The code:

```
CartesianChart ch = new CartesianChart
{
    Series = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "",
            Values = new ChartValues<double> { 1, 1, 2, 3 ,5 }
        }
    }
};
```

The error message:

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'OrientationConverter' was not found in namespace 'LiveCharts.Uwp'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]
```

Can anyone give me an advice in this case, please?